# AWS DMS - Scheduled DB Migration

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, aws-dms

I have Postgresql db in RDS. I need to fetch data from a bunch of tables in postgresql db and push data into a S3 bucket every hour. I only want the delta changes (any new inserts / updates) to be sent in the hourly. Is it possible to do this using DMS or is EMR a better tool for performing this activity?

Comment: frankly saying I don't see any obvious way how you are going to do it with DMS or EMR... Please explain

Comment: @VaoTsun what would be the alternate way of doing this ? I thought of writing a spark job that would poll oracle dB at pre-determined intervals , create a file and push it to S3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create an automated environment of migration data from RDS to S3 using AWS DMS (Data Migration Service) tasks.

1. Create a source endpoint (reading your RDS database - Postgres, MySQL, Oracle, etc...);
2. Create a target endpoint using S3 as an engine endpoint (read it: [Using Amazon S3 as a Target for AWS Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.S3.html));
3. Create a replication instance, responsible to make a bridge between source data and target endpoint (you will only pay while processing);
4. Create a database migration task using the option 'Replication data change only' on migration type field;
5. Create a cron lambda, which starts a DMS task, with stack Python following these instructions of this articles [Lambda with scheduled events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) e [Start DMS tasks with boto3 in Python](https://blog.nolanemirot.com/2016/09/16/start-dms-tasks-with-boto3-in-python/).

Connecting these resources above you may can have what you want.

Regards,

Renan S.